# DocuSign SMS Authentication

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am using DocuSign Soap API to send envelopes. It is working great. However SMS authentication is not working.

Phone Authentication is working as it should. I am using a demo DocuSign account, and in one of the threads I read that SMS needs to be enabled.

I checked DocuSign settings, but did not find any option under Admin >> Settings >> Authentication

```
pdfRecipient.RequireIDLookup = true;

            //Phone Numbers
            DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfString phoneNumbers = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfString();
            phoneNumbers.SenderProvidedNumber = new List<String>{'4081231234'};

            //Phone Authentication - WORKING
            /* pdfRecipient.IDCheckConfigurationName = 'Phone Auth $';
            DocuSignAPI.RecipientPhoneAuthentication phoneAuthentication = new DocuSignAPI.RecipientPhoneAuthentication();
            phoneAuthentication.RecipMayProvideNumber = true;
            phoneAuthentication.SenderProvidedNumbers = phoneNumbers;
            pdfRecipient.PhoneAuthentication = phoneAuthentication; */

            //SMS Authentication - NOT WORKING
            pdfRecipient.IDCheckConfigurationName = 'SMS Auth $';
            DocuSignAPI.RecipientSMSAuthentication smsAuthentication = new DocuSignAPI.RecipientSMSAuthentication();
            smsAuthentication.SenderProvidedNumbers = phoneNumbers;            
            pdfRecipient.SMSAuthentication = smsAuthentication;
```

It should send the envelope but instead I'm getting this error message -

```
Web service callout failed: 
WebService returned a SOAP Fault: 
Recipient SMS authentication specified but information missing. 
faultcode=soap:Client 
faultactor=https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx
```

I am passing accountId, recipientName, recipientId, recipientEmail as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please UPVOTE all userful answers, including those to others' questions. And PLEASE accept/check the most useful answer to your own questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is only adding the phone number to the first list but not the smsAuth list like this:

```
RecipientSMSAuthentication smsAuth = new RecipientSMSAuthentication();
smsAuth.SenderProvidedNumbers = new List<String>();
smsAuth.SenderProvidedNumbers.Add("4155551212");
```

Comment: Thanks @Inbar but unfortunately that is not true. I am assigning the phone numbers to var "phoneNumbers" and using that for both Phone and SMS authentication. And "Phone Authentication" logic is commented out , so there is no change to that variable.

Comment: oh, I see, I missed how you did that. Then I guess there's a different issue. I assume you confirmed your account has SMS auth? you can check that using the web app directly to see if you can set it from the UI

Comment: do you know how to check API logs? these may have some hints into what is going on

Comment: Thanks @Inbar. Check the API logs, it does not have any trace of SMS authentication. How to check if account has SMS auth enabled? That may be the missing link.

Comment: while sending from the UI, are you able to select SMS Auth for the recipient? It will be at the same place where Phone Auth is present (a drop down) under `Select access authentication` section.

Comment: You can also create a new sandbox account. These have SMS auth now

Comment: Thank you Inbar. We consulted with Docusign and they confirmed SMS auth is enabled. We are working with them to see why SMS auth is not working as documented. We also check the debug logs, it says that phone number is not passed. But that is not the case. We also tested by hard coding the phone number, same result. Will post a comment once they identify what the issue is. Thank you again.